# Empty body using Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I can't seem to get the Express `bodyParser` function to work when sending a `POST` request with an image attached (with the Content-Type header set to `multipart/form-data`). The `console.log` in the code below simply returns `{}`. Any ideas?

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post("/photo", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
app.listen(80);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at the req.files property for file uploads

http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files

More info here:

http://howtonode.org/78e21b7d5503a5b2b372f6c2a5de077a1e809267/really-simple-file-uploads

Answer (score 2):

If you're uploading the image using a file input then you might want to look at [`req.files`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files) instead -- if I understand correctly `req.body` only contains the POSTed fields that aren't files.